# Dynamic scheduling overhead

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, openmp

I have 2 loops, but I only want to parallelize the inner loop, since the pre- and post-processing can't be done in parallel. All `foo()` function calls together take 99% of the time, so I expect to get linear speedups when I parallelize the for loop with a `pragma omp for`, like on the code below. However, I only get a speedup of 1.87x for 2 threads. 
On the code below, `nodelist` contains the data structures used by `foo()`. These structures are a few small vectors and a matrix (`foo()` is compute bound). I'm using dynamic scheduling because each `foo()` call might have different execution times.

```
while (changed){
    //do some preprocessing

    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) num_threads(N_THREADS) private(j)
    for (j = 0; j <= DIM - beta; j++) {

        int tid = omp_get_thread_num();

        res[j] = foo(mu, c, j, j+beta-1, nodelist[tid], out[j]);

    }

    //do some post-processing (which updates changed)
}
```

I also tried to define single regions on the pre- and post-processing and to spawn the threads before the while loop (like below), but it doesn't even work.

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(N_THREADS) 
{
    while (changed){
        #pragma omp single
        {
        //do some preprocessing
        } 


        #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic) private(j)
        for (j = 0; j <= DIM - beta; j++) {

            int tid = omp_get_thread_num();

            res[j] = foo(mu, c, j, j+beta-1, nodelist[tid], out[j]);

        }

        #pragma omp single
        {
            //do some post-processing (which updates changed)
        }
    }
}
```

When profiling the first code with Xcode's Instruments, the load seemed to be well balanced (51.4% on 1 thread and 47.6% on the other thread). For 4 threads I get similar results, where each thread takes 23.4%-25% of the total execution time, but the speedups (in comparison to the number of threads that were used) are even worse (at 3.35x). I think the problem could be the dynamic scheduling overhead. I'm using dynamic scheduling because when testing the others, with static scheduling the OpenMP runtime system can't balance the work efficiently, while with guided scheduling it gets really close to dynamic, but slightly worse. Does someone have some tips on where I am loosing performance and on how to possibly improve it?

Thanks

Comment: How many iterations are there in the inner loop? For a reasonable large number of iterations, you could try with larger chunk size, e.g. `schedule(dynamic,5)` to have each thread do chunks of 5 consecutive iterations before requesting a new one. Also, which compiler suite are you using?

Comment: @HristoIliev In the case I mentioned, the for loop only performs 21 iterations. On the other hand, the while loop executes 97 times. I'm using GNU gcc 4.6.1 on Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: I assume that foo is rather slow otherwise you would have some issue with false sharing writing to `res[j]` for only 21 iterations?  What is your processor? How many physical and logical cores does it have?

Comment: @Zboson Yes, foo() is rather slow comparing to rest of the program. My CPU is an Intel Xeon E5-2670 @ 2.60GHz with 16 physical and 32 logical cores.

Comment: The E5-2670 has 8 physical cores. You must have a dual socket system with two E5-2670 processors.  In which case with two threads one thread is running on one processor and one thread on another processor because the default thread topology on Linux is scattered.

Comment: Dynamic can not balance the load perfectly. If you have a small number of iterations and all other iterations finish one thread will still take much longer. But let's assume that the that for close iterations (e.g. iterations 3,4 are close but not 1,20) the load is more or less balanced. You could try `schedule(static,1)`. With this even iterations will be run by one thread and odd by another (with two threads) but it won't suffer from the overhead of dynamic. I have no idea if it will be better but it's worth trying.

Comment: Incidentally, what boost do you get when you run with 16 threads?

Comment: @Zboson I used static, but the results I got were the same as with `schedule(dynamic,1)`. For 16 threads, I get a speedup of 5.97x

Comment: I don't know. 5.97x is not very good. I meant to say one thread could take much longer still. With 16 threads you have serious false sharing as each thread is probably writing to the same cache line (and maybe even much worse since two processors are writing to the same page). But if `foo` is slow enough it probably does not matter but that's the only thing left I can think of that might make a difference.

Comment: Why is `nodelist` a function of the thread number? How are you constructing the nodelist per thread? In most cases there are better ways of doing what you want without using the thread number. Can you add some code about nodelist?

Comment: Can you add some code about `foo`? Does `foo` write to memory or only read from memory?

Comment: @Zboson `foo` reads and writes to the structures allocated inside `nodelist` on the position of the respective thread ID. `nodelist` is a struct which contains some arrays. I use it this way because it allows me to allocate the structures that need to be private to each thread only once. `mu` and `c` are also arrays, whose values are only read inside of `foo`, but never updated.

Comment: I would guess a combination of poor load balancing and Amdahl's Law.  It is hard to get a small number of long running tasks to balance well.

Comment: @dohashi When I profiled the code the results were totally different. The parallel region takes more than 99% of the time and each thread does about 50% of the work for 2 threads and 25% for 4 threads. I believe that the problem could be the `#pragma omp parallel` inside of the loop. What do you think about this?

Comment: Your parallel section is being run multiple times, so you could have poor load balancing in each run, but the profile averages out over multiple runs.